# Defining general odd function

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, symbolic

I would like to define some function $f$ that is odd, $f(-x)=-f(x)$, and can be used in symbolic computations. I am a bit more ambitious than [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342237/how-can-i-define-a-abstract-odd-function-in-mathematica). 
One way of achieving my goal is to use Mathematica's function OrderedQ to define

```
f[0] = 0;
f[x_] /; OrderedQ @ {x,-x} := -f[-x]
```

This does the job, giving e.g.

```
f /@ {-x, x-y, -x+y}
(* Out: {-f[x], -f[-x+y], f[-x+y]} *)
```

What I would *really* like, though, is to define an odd function $g$ that produces the aesthetically more pleasing

```
(* Out: {-g[x], g[x-y], -g[x-y]} *)
```

The reason for the mismatch must have to do with the internal ordering that Mathematica uses. How do I get a function yielding my preferred result?

NB. The above is adapted from Section 5.6 of Grozin's *Introduction to Mathematica for Physicists*, who instead sets

```
h[0] = 0;
h[x_] /; Not @ OrderedQ @ {-x,x} := -h[-x]
```

Like $f$ this yields

```
(* Out: {-h[x], -h[-x+y], h[-x+y]} *)
```

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thanks, I edited the text and renamed the second function to avoid possible confusion. Just out of curiosity, can you give me an example where $f$ and $h$ give different results?

Comment: It works now.  I deleted my what I tried before.  It could have been an error on my part, but I can't check.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe use [`` Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[] ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=SyntacticNegativeQ):

```
ClearAll[g];
g[0] = 0;
g[x_] /; Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[x] := -g[-x];

g /@ {-x, x - y, -x + y, -x - y, x + y, -2, 2, -2.}
(*  {-g[x], g[x - y], -g[x - y], -g[x + y], g[x + y], -g[2], g[2], -g[2.]}  *)
```

I'm not sure if it covers all use cases in the way desired, but it prevents the argument beginning with a minus sign.  (It might not work on a negative symbolic constant, but I can't think of one. The constants `Pi`, `E`, and so forth are all positive.)

Comment: That is wonderful! I was just trying to construct my own sort of Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ from CoefficientList.

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to work and is elegant! Could you perhaps briefly explain what the function Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ does and why this works?

Comment: @JulesLamers What I know comes from the link I put in my answer, which is not a lot.  It's an internal, undocumented function that seems to indicate whether the expression would start with a minus sign (in `StandardForm`, maybe). It works like this: If `x` starts with a minus, then negate it and return `-g[-x]`.

Comment: This is cute-- You can evaluate `g` numerically, but not symbolically, over a symmetric interval: `NIntegrate[g[x], {x, -2, 2}]` evaluates to `0.`, but `Integrate[g[x], {x, -2, 2}]` returns unevaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `f` forces that any argument `z` of `f` is the smallest of `z` and `-z` with respect to the default ordering. Therefore, with your definition of `f`, it is impossible to get an output `f[x-y]`, since this automatically will evaluate to `f[-x+y]`.

So I restricted your definition a bit and came to the following, not very elegant, solution:

```
Clear[f];
f[0]=0;
f[x_?NumericQ]/;OrderedQ@{x,-x}:=-f[-x];
f[ x_] /; Quiet[x[[1]]<0 || x[[1,1]]<0] := -f[Expand[-x]]

f/@{-x,x-y,-x+y}

(* {-f[x],f[x-y],-f[x-y]} *)
```

I hope this also suits your needs. Otherwise, I think you have to use a different ordering in your definition of an odd function.

Comment: Thanks, although as you say it is not very elegant, that does indeed seem to do what I want. Just to see how versatile this is: Does Mathematica have any other orderings available? And suppose I would like $x-y$ but $z-x$, is it hard to define one's own ordering where, say, $x$ comes before $y$ but after $z$?

Comment: This seems to be not so simple as I thought it was. Have a look at the documentation of MonomialList, where there is a survey of  possible orderings.