# Define multivariate even general function

Tags: function-construction, symbolic, pattern-matching

I want to define a multivariate even function. This question shows how to do it for a single variable function [Defining general odd function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126738/defining-general-odd-function) but I don't see how to generalize the syntax to multiple variables. In particular, I want a general function f[x, y, z] with the properties
f[-x, y, z] = f[x, -y, z] = f[x, y, -z] = f[x, y, z]

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question correctly, because it seems obvious. Assume that f0 is not even. Then f= f0[Abs[x], Abs[y], Abs[z]] is even in x,y,z.

Comment: I need to take gradients, curls, and Laplacians of the function, and then simplify the result using the known symmetry. Abs doesn't have a derivative at 0 so doesn't work.

Comment: If a function is even at the origin, then the derivative must be zero.